# ember.js component sort model based on if property is set

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember and am using Ember.js 2.10. I'm trying to only use components instead of controllers. I'm trying to create a component that creates a list that is a list of links or just items and is sorted or not sorted based on the properties sent in. I have the link part working, but I can't seem to get the sort working without repeating a lot of code which makes me think I'm doing something wrong. I tried moving the sort logic into a computed property, but it doesn't work. If I don't specify a `sortBy` property, it still sorts the list. If I do specify as `sortBy` property, I don't get a list at all and the console.log shows what is returned as ComputedProperty.

This seems basic enough that I shouldn't have to do this, so if there is an Ember way of doing this, I'd like to know. Regardless, I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong for the academic value of it.

`app/components/column-list.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  classNames: ['column-list'],
  sortedItems: Ember.computed('items', 'sortBy', function() {
    if (this.get('sortBy') !== undefined) {
      let sd = [ this.get('sortBy') ];
      return Ember.computed.sort(this.get('items'), sd);
    } else {
      return this.get('items');
    }
  }),
});
```

`app/templates/components/column-list.hbs`

```
{{#if sortBy}}
  {{#each sortedItems as |item|}}
    <li>
       {{#if link}}
         {{#link-to link item.id}}
           {{yield item}}
         {{/link-to}}
       {{else}}
         {{yield item}}
       {{/if}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
{{else}}
  {{#each items as |item|}}
    <li>
       {{#if link}}
         {{#link-to link item.id}}
           {{yield item}}
         {{/link-to}}
       {{else}}
         {{yield item}}
       {{/if}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

`app/templates/category/index.hbs`

```
{{#column-list class="categories" sortBy="title" link="category.show" items=model as |i|}}
  {{i.title}}
{{/column-list}}
```

`mirage/fixtures/category.js`

```
export default [
  {
    id: 'main-dishes',
    title: 'Main Dishes',
  }, {
    id: 'cakes-pies-and-sweets',
    title: 'Cakes, Pies & Sweets',
  }, {
    id: 'langappie',
    title: 'Langappie',
  }, {
    id: 'dips-and-sauces',
    title: 'Dips & Sauces',
  }, {
    id: 'meat-dishes',
    title: 'Meat Dishes',
  }, {
    id: 'vegetable',
    title: 'Vegetable',
  }, {
    id: 'seafood-dishes',
    title: 'Seafood Dishes',
  }, {
    id: 'bread-and-cereals',
    title: 'Bread & Cereals',
  }
];
```

Update:

I twiddled the twiddle that @Jovica made and I'm getting "Assertion Failed: The sort definition for 'sortedItems' on  must be a function or an array of strings", so I think I still have something wrong. [Link to twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d40f3e7f793b7dfdbebfe182b6ce6cf3?openFiles=components.column-list.js%2C)

Update2:

I found that I had a typo in my twiddle and got it working properly. The [new twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d40f3e7f793b7dfdbebfe182b6ce6cf3?openFiles=components.column-list.js%2C) has the right fix. Now to figure out why ember-mirage is ordering the data without me asking, but that is a different problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I suggest you to write [a twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) instead of pasting a long code. By doing this, many answerers can play with your code.

Comment: About controllers, you might want to read this documentation: http://emberjs.com/learn/#faq-future-proof https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/controllers/#toc_common-questions

Comment: @locks I understand that controllers will remain with a few changes. This code seemed like the perfect candidate for a component as it could be reused many times in the app. Do you disagree? I just want to make sure I understand your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the `Ember.computed.sort` macro isn't doing what you think it is. You would have to use the sort methods on the Array class. The dependent keys are also not properly declared, it would be `items.[]` if the list is to be updated.

Here's a suggested solution that updates the sorting whenever the sort key that's passed into the component changes:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  dishes: foo,
  sortedItems: Ember.computed.sort('dishes', 'sortBy')

  didReceiveAttrs() {
    if (this.get('sortBy')) {
      this.set('sortBy', [ this.get('sortBy') ]);
    else {
      this.set('sortBy', []);
    }
  }
});
```

And here's the template you need, because when `sortBy` is an empty array, the computed macro will not sort the array:

```
{{#each sortedItems as |item|}}
  <li>
    {{#if link}}
      {{#link-to link item.id}}
        {{yield item}}
      {{/link-to}}
    {{else}}
      {{yield item}}
    {{/if}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Just so that I understand the difference between your solution and ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼@Jovica is that this code would resort the list if I passed in a new sortBy without having to reload the page (like a sort button with an action)? What if a new list item was added to the Ember Data asynchronously (web socket or something) or an item renamed, would the list be automatically be updated and sorted that the other would not be (I understand that Ember can update the DOM if the data changes, but I don't know how to do that yet)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sortedItems: Ember.computed('items', 'sortBy', function() {
  if (this.get('sortBy') !== undefined) {
    let sd = this.get('sortBy');
    return this.get('items').sortBy(sd);
  } else {
    return this.get('items');
  }
}),
```

or shorter version

```
sortedItems: Ember.computed('items', 'sortBy', function() {
  let sortTerm = this.get('sortBy'),
      items    = this.get('items');
  return Ember.isBlank(sortTerm) ? items : items.sortBy(sortTerm);
}
```

Comment: I make it work in this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1f66e42b3b9e906ae395885474e3483d?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.column-list.hbs)  but then I forgot this `sortBy` method in [`Ember.Array`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_sortBy) ..However I am not sure about returning `return Ember.computed.sort` patten. this will never work and we should never do that.Is my assumptions is right ?

Comment: @kumkanillam I'm not quite sure but I think that it can be used, but there's no need since sortBy method is much more suitable in this example.

Comment: Thank you. In your short version inclue return the result

Comment: @kumkanillam Thanks, I'm not sure does ternary operator does implicit return?

Comment: @JovicaŠuša I see that sortBy is method of Ember.Array, can you explain a little when you would use Ember.Array.sortBy() vs. Ember.computed.sort()? Is Ember.computed.sort() just a shorthand for Ember.computed(Ember.Array.sortBy())?

Comment: I think that when you need to have sorted computed property you should use computed.sort, so for your case @locks solution is more appropriate. No computed.sort is not shorthand for the code you posted.